# Connect two devices with ssh on local network

Tags: ssh, lan

I would like to connect 2 device (my company laptop, and a raspberry pi 3), I would like to develop on my laptop and test on raspberry using vs code and ssh. It's possible to connect the raspberry to lan(which is managed by my company),without actually using my company lan/proxy configuration. Basically I don't want my company detect the pi or the po' causing security issue since the pi is not well protected. The final result I want is like direct connect the laptop to the pi with the ethernet cable, but passing through my company cable system

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off-topic here on Super User. We won't help you lose your job trying to fool the IT department. Ask *them*.

Comment: Relevant answer on Meta: [*What is the definition of “corporate IT support”?*](https://meta.superuser.com/a/9253/432690) "The distinction for me is essentially whether we can help the user without circumventing restrictions that have been put in place by their IT support."

Comment: The security issue is not caused by the company *detecting* the Pi... it's caused by the Pi being *present*. It's still an issue whether it's detected or not.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean detecting the pi is a security issue, of course... For the other 2 comment, the problem is that I'm not trying to circumventing the restrictions, I don't know even if they are.. Mine isn'teven aa It corporate but a laboratory. I'm just trying to build a tool without making my life too much harder without involving my IT thechs for such a stupid thing. The pi will be connected only for the time the software is developed. Once done it will be disconnected. Said thattthe qquestion is not aboutccircumventing the rules, but connect the pi need config or just work out of the box?